# Understanding a code snippet for my app

Tags: java, android

I have found example code to put into my Android app to make an image zoomable and dragable. I understand most of it but there is an if statement that I don't quite understand.

```
            if (mode == DRAG)
            {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                if (view.getLeft() >= -392)
                {
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                }
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 5f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    scale = newDist/oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
```

What is the significance of the -392 in the if statement?

Comment: Why don't you ask the original poster? Tatiana_aha at http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread1174111.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author of the code decided he didn't want something to be dragged too far. So he put a hardcoded limit. 392 is just what he picked as a limit, it was likely based on the size of the view on some device.

However, it is a bad idea on two counts:

1. You ought to make it a named constant.
2. 392 pixels is a different amount on different devices due to pixel densities. It should probably be specified as `dp` and scaled at runtime.

Comment: Got it!  I don't need that limit so I removed it.  Thanks.